Mapping structure in LaTeX3
I'm developing a LaTeX class for typesetting theses at the University of Trento, aiming to streamline every aspect of the thesis formatting process.
One feature I want to implement is allowing candidates to specify their department (e.g., "disi" or "DISI"), after which the class would automatically map the input to the appropriate string in Italian or English.
I read on the LaTeX3 specification about the \str_casefold:n for caseless comparison of text but I couldn't figure out how to use it.
Currently, I am using the \iflanguage function from the babel package to check the selected language and translate the string accordingly. However, I feel this approach is not very efficient. Additionally, I need to manually hard-code each string and include \space for formatting, which adds complexity.
Is there a mechanism to implement a more efficient and scalable solution for handling department names and translations based on the selected language, ideally leveraging LaTeX3's tools for text processing?
Specifically, I’d like to:

Use a case-insensitive mechanism to recognize department inputs (e.g., "disi" or "DISI");
Automatically map these inputs to pre-defined strings in both Italian and English;
Avoid hard-coding \space for formatting and instead use a cleaner, more structured approach.

Could you suggest how to achieve this using LaTeX3 functions like \str_casefold:n or other tools in the expl3 package? Additionally, is there a better way to handle language-specific mappings without relying solely on \iflanguage from the babel package?
\PassOptionsToClass{11pt, preview, margin=2mm}{standalone}

\documentclass{standalone}% default language: english
% \documentclass[english]{standalone}
% \documentclass[italian]{standalone}

\usepackage{babel}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\department}{m}{\str_gset:Nn \g_unitn_department_str {#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\degree}{m}{\str_gset:Nn \g_unitn_degree_str {#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\course}{m}{\str_gset:Nn \g_unitn_course_str {#1}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\printdepartment}{}{
    \str_case_e:nn { \g_unitn_department_str }
    {
        {disi}
          {\iflanguage{italian}
            {Dipartimento\space di\space Ingegneria\space e\space Scienza\space dell'Informazione}%
            {Department\space of\space Information\space Engineering\space and\space Computer\space Science}
          }
        {dicam}
          {\iflanguage{italian}
            {Dipartimento\space di\space Ingegneria\space Civile,\space Ambientale\space e\space Meccanica}%
            {Department\space of\space Civil,\space Environmental\space and\space Mechanical\space Engineering}
          }
    }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\printdegree}{}{
    \str_case_e:nn { \g_unitn_degree_str }
    {
        {bachelor}  {\iflanguage{italian}{Laurea\space Triennale\space in}{Bachelor's\space Degree\space in}}
        {master}    {\iflanguage{italian}{Laurea\space Magistrale\space in}{Master's\space Degree\space in}}
        {doctorate} {\iflanguage{italian}{Dottorato\space in}{Doctoral\space Programme\space in}}
    }
}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\maketitle}{}{
  \begin{titlepage}
    \centering
    {\textsc{\printdepartment}\par}
    
    {\Large
        \printdegree\\%
        \g_unitn_course_str
    \par}
  \end{titlepage}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

% possible values: disi/dicam
\department{disi}
% possible values: bachelor/master/doctorate
\degree{bachelor}
\course{Computer Science}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}



I would add language-sensitive strings using the babel mechanism so that you use e.g. \mastersname in the l3 code. then in the l3 code, I'd implement the user interface us l3keys so you can just set up .choice keys with the various possibilities. but please provide a complete minimal example here - questions shouldn't rely on external links. you don't need (and we don't want to read) the whole class. you really just need one example, as far as I can see, with two or three possibilities. the idea would be for somebody here to show you the method, so you can extend it to other cases.

I have included a self-contained minimal working example. Please let me know if there are any issues or if further adjustments are needed.

I wonder why you base it on standalone. I use this class to create drawings with size unknown in advance. I.e. including several ones give page breaks with variable page sizes …

simply for a matter of convenience in producing the image and because it allows me to visually isolate the problem, the unitnthesis class is based off the book class

Now that I've seen Egreg's solution, I would like to see how @cfr ’s approach is implemented as well, so I can add more tools to my toolkit and understand the pros and cons of each method.

I suggest to store information in a property list.
\documentclass[english]{article}
%\documentclass[italian]{article}

\usepackage{babel}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\str_new:N \g_unitn_department_str
\str_new:N \g_unitn_degree_str
\str_new:N \g_unitn_course_str
\prop_new:N \g_unitn_attributes_prop

\NewDocumentCommand{\department}{m}
 {
  \str_gset:Ne \g_unitn_department_str { \str_casefold:n {#1} }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\degree}{m}
 {
  \str_gset:Ne \g_unitn_degree_str { \str_casefold:n {#1} }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\course}{m}
 {
  \str_gset:Ne \g_unitn_course_str { \str_casefold:n {#1} }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\printdepartment}{}
 {
  \prop_item:Ne \g_unitn_attributes_prop { department @ \g_unitn_department_str @ \languagename }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\printdegree}{}
 {
  \prop_item:Ne \g_unitn_attributes_prop { degree @ \g_unitn_degree_str @ \languagename }
 }

\RenewDocumentCommand{\maketitle}{}{
  \begin{titlepage}
    \centering
    {\textsc{\printdepartment}\par}
    {\Large
        \printdegree\\
        \str_use:N \g_unitn_course_str
    \par}
  \end{titlepage}
}

% a facility to set attributes
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__unitn_attribute:nnnn
 {
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_unitn_attributes_prop { #1 @ #2 @ italian } {#3}
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_unitn_attributes_prop { #1 @ #2 @ english } {#4}
 }
\group_begin:
\char_set_catcode_space:n {`\ }

\__unitn_attribute:nnnn{department}{disi}
  {Dipartimento di Ingegneria e Scienza dell'Informazione}
  {Department of Information Engineering and Computer Science}
\__unitn_attribute:nnnn{department}{dicam}
  {Dipartimento di Ingegneria Civile, Ambientale e Meccanica}
  {Department of Civil, Environmental and Mechanical Engineering}

\__unitn_attribute:nnnn{degree}{bachelor}{Laurea Triennale in}{Bachelor's Degree in}
\__unitn_attribute:nnnn{degree}{master}{Laurea Magistrale in}{Master's Degree in}
\__unitn_attribute:nnnn{degree}{doctorate}{Dottorato in}{Doctoral Programme in}
\group_end:

\ExplSyntaxOff

% possible values: disi/dicam
\department{disi}
% possible values: bachelor/master/doctorate
\degree{bachelor}
\course{Computer Science}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}


With italian as default language:

By the way, if you want a space when in the scope of \ExplSyntaxOn, you use ~ (and \nobreakspace if you want a nonbreaking space).

I’m currently using the ProvidesExplClass command to declare the class, so I’m not explicitly using the \ExplSyntaxOn and \ExplSyntaxOff flags. Is there anything I should be aware of?

@EmanueleNardi I modified the code. You just devote a section of the class file to attribute setting and, in order not to be forced to use ~, you can locally set the category code of the space to the standard value. This is what I do in kantlipsum.

It's works like a charm!

while reading the documentation of kantlipsum, I noticed that it redirects to a potentially malicious site. I've emailed you the details.

This implementation does not account for the fact that the default language should be English. As a result, if I declare \documentclass{article} without specifying the language, I encounter the following error: "There's no line here to end."

@EmanueleNardi If your class loads babel it should set a main language. If babel is not loaded, \languagename expands to english

If I explicitly set the language within the class using \RequirePackage[english]{babel}, it overrides the language setting defined in the global options.

Related: A class with default language settings

Would it be a good idea to implement a mechanism similar to the one described in this answer?

@EmanueleNardi babel has changed a lot since 2013.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
